# Devise Sign In issue with jQuery Mobile and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to get devise to login but I'm getting a 500 error due to missing template. Any idea? Why is it trying to render `devise/sessions/create` ?

Rails 3.1

---

I'm using the mobylette gem: https://github.com/tscolari/mobylette
I have devise configured with:

`config.navigational_formats = [:"*/*", "*/*", :html, :mobile]`

---

`Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 145msActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template devise/sessions/create, application/create with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml], :formats=>[:mobile], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. Searched in:  * "/Users/Armageddon/Projects/Business/jquerymobiletest/app/views"  * "/Users/Armageddon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180-patched@jquerymobiletest/gems/devise-1.4.9/app/views"):  Rendered /Users/Armageddon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180-patched@jquerymobiletest/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/missing_template.erb within rescues/layout (0.5ms)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had to make the following changes to make this work:

config/initializers/devise.rb

`config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = false`
Had to make that false otherwise jQuery mobile sends XHR requests to login and you get a 401 error.

`config.navigational_formats = [:"*/*", "*/*", :html, :mobile]`

This otherwise it wouldn't recognize the format. You'd think this would handle the redirections but it actually doesn't. You need to do one more thing.

It's hacky to me so I added it to:
config/initializers/devise_hack.rb

`ActionController::Responder.class_eval do
  alias :to_mobile :to_html
end`

Now it works.

One more thing though; in my application.rb I have this for mobylette to setup my mobile stuff:

`respond_to_mobile_requests :skip_xhr_requests => false, :fall_back => :html`

Between the `Responder.class_eval` and the `:fall_back => :html` you'd think that these wouldn't be necessary. A lot of the config's written seem to be the same thing and or duplicated. However without all of these settings it just doesn't work.

Comment: What settings do I need to change if I am using [mobile-fu](https://github.com/brendanlim/mobile-fu) ?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, I solved it by creating a file in app>views>devise>sessions called create.mobile.erb I have the following code in it:

```
<section id="login_redirect_page" data-role="page"> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = "<%= root_path %>"
  </script>
</section>
```

It just puts the create view in a jquery mobile block and redirects to the root_path. I'm looking for better ways to do this though so I'll post if I come across something.

Comment: I also found this: in config/initializers/devise.rb uncomment this line

config.navigational_formats = [:"*/*", "*/*", :html]

and add your mobile format to this like :mobile